# Python Beautiful soup retrieval gives an error response 'NoneType object has no attribute getText

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to retrieve data from a google.com query using requests library and beautiful soup library.
Im tearing my hair out. Whatever version of code I try I get an error.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="LGOjhe" data-attrid="wa:/description" aria-level="3" role="heading" data-hveid="CAYQAA">
<span class="ILfuVd NA6bn">
<span class="hgKElc">
Right-click the speaker icon and select &quot;Open Sound Settings.&quot; 3. Scroll down to &quot;Input.&quot; Windows will show you which <b>microphone</b> is currently your default — in other words, which one it&#39;s using right now — and a blue bar showing your volume levels. Try talking into your <b>microphone</b>.
</span>
</span>
```

I use the following code:

```
        page = rq.get('http://www.google.com/search?q=where%20is%20my%20microphone',  headers = hd)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        #answer = soup.find('span', {'class_': 'hgKElc'}).getText()
        answer = soup.find('div', {'class_': 'kJ442'}).getText()
```

I get an error that the response of none does not have a `getText()` method. which means my retrieval method has failed:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\study\PythonProjectVoice\PythonVoice03.py", line 115, in respond
    answer = soup.find('div', {'class_': 'kJ442'}).getText()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Any answers much appreciated.

Comment: That means `soup.find('div', {'class_': 'kJ442'})` is None, try with `soup.find('div').getText()`

Answer (score 0):

There are different things, that could be improved, but the error occurred cause there is no `<div>` with a class like `kJ442`

To get the text of the `<span>` use:

```
soup.find('span', {'class': 'hgKElc'}).get_text()
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="LGOjhe" data-attrid="wa:/description" aria-level="3" role="heading" data-hveid="CAYQAA">
<span class="ILfuVd NA6bn">
<span class="hgKElc">
Right-click the speaker icon and select &quot;Open Sound Settings.&quot; 3. Scroll down to &quot;Input.&quot; Windows will show you which <b>microphone</b> is currently your default — in other words, which one it&#39;s using right now — and a blue bar showing your volume levels. Try talking into your <b>microphone</b>.
</span>
</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
soup.find('span', {'class': 'hgKElc'}).get_text()
```

Comment: He is using `html.parser` as a html parser, not `lxml`

Comment: @AvenDesta: Does not matter in this case, but thanks for mentioning, edited it.